# Typeorm is unable to generate migration files from entities

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using typeorm in one of my nestjs project. Whenever I want to generate a migration file based upon my entities I got the following message:

```
No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command
```

Meanwhile the database is empty.
This is my configuration. The file name is .env

```
# Database configuration
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = postgres
TYPEORM_HOST = localhost
TYPEORM_USERNAME = appuser
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = appuser
TYPEORM_DATABASE = messaging_db
TYPEORM_PORT = 5432
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = false
TYPEORM_LOGGING = true
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/models/.*ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS = migrations/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR= migrations
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN = true


# Application configuration
PORT = 8000
```

I have created a migrations folder at the root directory of the project where .env file resides and my entities are in the src/models folder.

Kindly assist.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like your entities glob pattern is incorrect. You've placed the star after the dot instead of before the dot

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. There is a saying when you are tired stop coding is true.

Comment: Don't leave empty spaces in the `.env` files, by the way, some libs have issues with that :)

Answer (score 1):

> No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command

I was facing the above issue due to missing "**export**" keyword for the entity class.

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity implements IUser {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    readonly id!: number;

    @Column()
    name!: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the decorator `@Entity()`. Another thing, you need to build the application after every change in the code to generate the migration. Hope it helps :)